# Vuforia sample application crash

Tags: android, vuforia

I'm trying to run some of the Vuforia's samples in eclipse, i "run as android application", then I run the application on my smartphone, an LG G2 mini with android 5.0.2.
When the application starts, shows me the description page of the application, I touch "Start". My screen turns white, than blac,than white again and in the end the application returns me to the home.
some suggestions?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to generate your api key in [Vuforia developer page](https://developer.vuforia.com/license-manager)
. also you need to add jni to your project and put .so libs in it (in my case vuforia-sdk-android-4-2-3\build\lib) ,put "armeabi-v7a" folder in "jniLibs" folder and you can now build your project.
if you using gradle your file structure should be like this:

```
app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libVuforia.so
```

Comment: Thank you for your very fast and useful answer. I just did not understand the last part of your answer, i forgot to say I'm developing on windows, so iI was not able to follow the path you described. Thank you.

Comment: which IDE do you use? I used "Android studio" and last part is a my project's file structure

Comment: I use Eclipse, but I discovered tha maybe my device is not supported by vuforia. I'm seearching more informations about supported devices.

Answer (score 0):

Is very important to had libVuforia.so in the correct place according MHP. You have to get SampleApplicationSesion, the api key inin line 336.